# How to get multiple substrings from string in Android/Java ?

Tags: java, regex, string

I need some help to extract multiple substrings from a string. An example of a string is as given below:

```
String str = "What is <Mytag a exp 5 exp 3> written as a single power of <i>a</i> <Mytag yx4> and the double power of <b>x+y</b> <Mytag 3xy4>";
```

I am trying to get substrings Between "<Mytag"  and ">"

so my desire output will be 

**1) a exp 5 exp 3

2) yx4 

3) 3xy4**

I have tried with Scanner and substring everything I getting first string successfully but the problem with getting second and third occurrence.

in substring methods I am successfully getting index of all tages "<Mytag" but not able to get correct index of ">" because it comes with Bold and italic also.

Comment: You can try regex processing of the string

Comment: Getting the closest `>` after each `<mytag` should work, am I right?

Comment: `indexOf()` can also be written in this form `int indexOf(int ch, int startIndex)` . Here you can specify the `startIndex` to be 1 more than the previous index found. Last you should also check of `IndexOutOfBounds` exception on performing these actions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **Rohit Jain** said, with regular expressions. Here is functional code:

```
// import java.io.Console;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class RegexTestHarness {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    // Console console = System.console();  // Not needed

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<Mytag([^>]*)>");

    String myString = "What is <Mytag a exp 5 exp 3> written as a single power of <i>a</i> <Mytag yx4> and the double power of <b>x+y</b> <Mytag 3xy4>";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);

    while (matcher.find()) {
      // Rohit Jain observation
      System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }

  }
}
```

Source: [Java Regex tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)

Comment: But why are you using `replace`? Can't you just get the `group 1`?

Comment: Really? I did not know. I know about the backwhack but in Java I never used it.

Comment: Ok, I will take it in account. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use Regex for that: -

```
"<Mytag ([^>]*)>"
```

And get the `group 1` from the above regex. You need to use it with [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class, and use [`Matcher#find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method with a `while` loop to find all the matching substrings.