# How to get a multiple substrings from a string

Tags: java

I have a string that might look like this:

```
searchText = search:kind:(reports) unit.id:(("CATS (WILLIAMS)"~1) OR ("DOGS (JAMES)"~1))
```

I need to extact any values that may exist in the quotation marks so in this case it would be:

`CATS (WILLIAMS)` and `DOGS (JAMES)`

Not sure I understand how using indexOf and subString will get me a text string since they depend on integer values... Can someone show me some examples of how this might be done? Thanks

Ok figured out the basics, but I need it to extract every value in " " not just the first instance. The below extacts the value then converts the name into an id then replaces the name with an id, but ONLY does the first instance.

```
       String unitIdStart = "\"";
       String unitIdEnd = "\"~";

       int unitIdStartIndex = searchText.indexOf(unitIdStart);
       if( unitIdStartIndex != -1 ) {
           int unitIdEndIndex = searchText.indexOf(unitIdEnd, unitIdStartIndex);
           if( unitIdEndIndex != -1 );
           {

               String unitName = searchText.substring(unitIdStartIndex+1, unitIdEndIndex);
               Unit backToId = UnitRepository.getIdFromName(unitName);
               String unitId = backToId.getId().toString();

               String searchTextWithUnitId = searchText.replace(unitName, unitId);
```

Comment: You use `indexOf` to retrieve the position of the borders (in your case the quotation marks). Then you can use `subString` to extract some text between the already retrieved border positions. Show us some code

Comment: The term you are looking for is regex.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473155/how-to-get-data-between-quotes-in-java AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574689/extract-a-substring-between-double-quotes-with-regular-expression-in-java. I think it is a duplicate question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678221/how-to-get-multiple-substrings-from-string-in-android-java